# Aurelia Babel unknown option base.modules error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs, aurelia

I downloaded the skeleton project from the [Aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.2/doc/article/a-production-setup) and tried starting it up by using the command:

```shell
gulp watch
```

However, I get the following error:

```shell
[09:48:13] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: [BABEL] <filelocation>: Unknown option: base.modules
```

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read over one step, which was the `npm install` command which you have to execute from the project folder. I got some errors that the `CL.exe` file was missing and after some Googling, I found out that was due to me not having Visual Studio 2013 not installed, which kept the `utf-8 validator` package from not installing.

Answer (score 2):

did you follow the full project setup instructions on the docs page or in the [project's readme.md](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/README.md)?

> ### Running The App
>
> To run the app, follow these steps.
>
> 1. Ensure that [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) is installed. This provides the platform on which the build tooling runs.
> 2. From the project folder, execute the following command:
>
>    `npm install`
> 3. Ensure that [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) is installed globally. If you need to install it, use the following command:
>
>    `npm install -g gulp`
> 4. Ensure that [jspm](http://jspm.io/) is installed globally. If you need to install it, use the following command:
>
>    `npm install -g jspm`
> 5. Install the client-side dependencies with jspm:
>
>    `jspm install -y`
> 6. To run the app, execute the following command:
>
>    `gulp watch`
> 7. Browse to http://localhost:9000 to see the app. You can make changes in the code found under `src` and the
>      browser should auto-refresh itself as you save files.

Comment: I fixed it myself, thanks for your support though. See the edit.